# Typescript error messages for javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I only have a minified version of the javascript code below. It works as is but I needed to integrate this code inside of a typescript file. It still works pretty well at runtime but in my editor (Visual Studio Code) I got errors.

[image]

Below is the code.

```
!function(e){"use strict";function i(i,a){var s=i.outerWidth(!0),o={};if(!i.is(":visible")&&!n){switch(n=!0,i.addClass("ps-active-panel").css({position:"fixed",top:0,height:"100%","z-index":9999999999}),i.data(a),e("html").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").bind("touchmove",!1),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeIn(200),a.side){case"left":i.css({left:"-"+s+"px",right:"auto"}),o.left="+="+s;break;case"right":i.css({left:"auto",right:"-"+s+"px"}),o.right="+="+s}t.animate({},a.duration),i.show().animate(o,a.duration,function(){n=!1,"function"==typeof a.onOpen&&a.onOpen()})}}var t=e("body"),n=!1;e.panelslider=function(t,n){var a=e(".ps-active-panel");n=e.extend({},{side:"left",duration:200,clickClose:!0,onOpen:null},n),a.is(":visible")&&a[0]!=t[0]?e.panelslider.close(function(){i(t,n)}):a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")||i(t,n)},e.panelslider.close=function(i){var a=e(".ps-active-panel"),s=a.data("duration"),o=a.outerWidth(!0),l={};if(a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")&&!n){switch(n=!0,a.data("side")){case"left":l.left="-="+o;break;case"right":l.right="-="+o}a.animate(l,s),t.animate({},s,function(){a.fadeOut(200),a.removeClass("ps-active-panel"),e("html").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeOut(200),n=!1,i&&i()})}},e(document).bind("click keyup",function(i){var t=e(".ps-active-panel");"keyup"==i.type&&27!=i.keyCode||t.is(":visible")&&t.data("clickClose")&&e.panelslider.close()}),e(document).on("click",".ps-active-panel",function(e){e.stopPropagation()}),e.fn.panelslider=function(i){return this.on("click",function(t){var n=e(".ps-active-panel"),a=e(this.getAttribute("href"));n.is(":visible")&&a[0]==n[0]?e.panelslider.close():e.panelslider(a,i),t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()}),this}}(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-open").panelslider({side:"right",clickClose:!0,duration:400}),jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-close").on("click",function(){return jQuery.panelslider.close(),!1})});
```

What can be done on this code to avoid TypeScript errors in my editor ?

**EDIT**

For this moment, I copy/paste minified javascript code inside another TypeScript file (wrap it in `panel` function) and it works at runtime but got errors in my editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **//@ts-ignore** directive in order to **avoid typings** or you can create our **declaration file (d.ts)** for panelslider plugin.

First let's move all plugin related code into a separate file, name it *panelslider.plugin.ts*. so content should be like this, here I have imported jQuery and added **@ts-ignore** directives to get rid of all errors.

```
import jQuery from "jquery";

// @ts-ignore

    !function(e){"use strict";function i(i,a){var s=i.outerWidth(!0),o={};if(!i.is(":visible")&&!n){switch(n=!0,i.addClass("ps-active-panel").css({position:"fixed",top:0,height:"100%","z-index":9999999999}),i.data(a),e("html").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").bind("touchmove",!1),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeIn(200),a.side){case"left":i.css({left:"-"+s+"px",right:"auto"}),o.left="+="+s;break;case"right":i.css({left:"auto",right:"-"+s+"px"}),o.right="+="+s}t.animate({},a.duration),i.show().animate(o,a.duration,function(){n=!1,"function"==typeof a.onOpen&&a.onOpen()})}}var t=e("body"),n=!1;e.panelslider=function(t,n){var a=e(".ps-active-panel");n=e.extend({},{side:"left",duration:200,clickClose:!0,onOpen:null},n),a.is(":visible")&&a[0]!=t[0]?e.panelslider.close(function(){i(t,n)}):a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")||i(t,n)},e.panelslider.close=function(i){var a=e(".ps-active-panel"),s=a.data("duration"),o=a.outerWidth(!0),l={};if(a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")&&!n){switch(n=!0,a.data("side")){case"left":l.left="-="+o;break;case"right":l.right="-="+o}a.animate(l,s),t.animate({},s,function(){a.fadeOut(200),a.removeClass("ps-active-panel"),e("html").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeOut(200),n=!1,i&&i()})}},e(document).bind("click keyup",function(i){var t=e(".ps-active-panel");"keyup"==i.type&&27!=i.keyCode||t.is(":visible")&&t.data("clickClose")&&e.panelslider.close()}),e(document).on("click",".ps-active-panel",function(e){e.stopPropagation()}),e.fn.panelslider=function(i){return this.on("click",function(t){var n=e(".ps-active-panel"),a=e(this.getAttribute("href"));n.is(":visible")&&a[0]==n[0]?e.panelslider.close():e.panelslider(a,i),t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()}),this}}(jQuery);
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-open").panelslider({side:"right",clickClose:!0,duration:400}),jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-close").on("click",function(){return jQuery.panelslider.close(),!1})});
```

Code

```
import jQuery from "jquery";

// @ts-ignore
import "./panelslider.plugin";

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("body")
        .find(".eskimo-panel-open")
        .panelslider({ side: "right", clickClose: !0, duration: 400 });

        jQuery("body")
            .find(".eskimo-panel-close")
            .on("click", function() {
                return jQuery.panelslider.close(), !1;
            });
});
```

Type declaration for *panelslider* plugin. Just add following code into  type declaration file(global.d.ts make sure ts complier honoring)

```
export type PanelSlider = {
    side: "right";
    clickClose: boolean;
    duration: number;
};

interface JQuery {
    panelslider(options: PanelSlider): void;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    panelslider: {
        close(): any;
    };
}
```

Comment: It works pretty well. I simply had to remove `export` in front of `type PanelSlider` otherwize I got errors and global.d.ts was not recognized.

Comment: Yes, you are right since it global.d.ts no need to export any type.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a minified js you can simply **ignore/exclude** that file in `tsconfig`.

tsconfig documentation [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TSLint you could wrap that code between these comments:

```
panel(){

/* tslint:disable */
!function(e){"use strict";function i(i,a){var s=i.outerWidth(!0),o={};if(!i.is(":visible")&&!n){switch(n=!0,i.addClass("ps-active-panel").css({position:"fixed",top:0,height:"100%","z-index":9999999999}),i.data(a),e("html").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").bind("touchmove",!1),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeIn(200),a.side){case"left":i.css({left:"-"+s+"px",right:"auto"}),o.left="+="+s;break;case"right":i.css({left:"auto",right:"-"+s+"px"}),o.right="+="+s}t.animate({},a.duration),i.show().animate(o,a.duration,function(){n=!1,"function"==typeof a.onOpen&&a.onOpen()})}}var t=e("body"),n=!1;e.panelslider=function(t,n){var a=e(".ps-active-panel");n=e.extend({},{side:"left",duration:200,clickClose:!0,onOpen:null},n),a.is(":visible")&&a[0]!=t[0]?e.panelslider.close(function(){i(t,n)}):a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")||i(t,n)},e.panelslider.close=function(i){var a=e(".ps-active-panel"),s=a.data("duration"),o=a.outerWidth(!0),l={};if(a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")&&!n){switch(n=!0,a.data("side")){case"left":l.left="-="+o;break;case"right":l.right="-="+o}a.animate(l,s),t.animate({},s,function(){a.fadeOut(200),a.removeClass("ps-active-panel"),e("html").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeOut(200),n=!1,i&&i()})}},e(document).bind("click keyup",function(i){var t=e(".ps-active-panel");"keyup"==i.type&&27!=i.keyCode||t.is(":visible")&&t.data("clickClose")&&e.panelslider.close()}),e(document).on("click",".ps-active-panel",function(e){e.stopPropagation()}),e.fn.panelslider=function(i){return this.on("click",function(t){var n=e(".ps-active-panel"),a=e(this.getAttribute("href"));n.is(":visible")&&a[0]==n[0]?e.panelslider.close():e.panelslider(a,i),t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()}),this}}(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-open").panelslider({side:"right",clickClose:!0,duration:400}),jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-close").on("click",function(){return jQuery.panelslider.close(),!1})});
/* tslint:enable */

}
```

For ESLint you should use:

```
panel(){

/* eslint-disable */
!function(e){"use strict";function i(i,a){var s=i.outerWidth(!0),o={};if(!i.is(":visible")&&!n){switch(n=!0,i.addClass("ps-active-panel").css({position:"fixed",top:0,height:"100%","z-index":9999999999}),i.data(a),e("html").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").addClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").bind("touchmove",!1),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeIn(200),a.side){case"left":i.css({left:"-"+s+"px",right:"auto"}),o.left="+="+s;break;case"right":i.css({left:"auto",right:"-"+s+"px"}),o.right="+="+s}t.animate({},a.duration),i.show().animate(o,a.duration,function(){n=!1,"function"==typeof a.onOpen&&a.onOpen()})}}var t=e("body"),n=!1;e.panelslider=function(t,n){var a=e(".ps-active-panel");n=e.extend({},{side:"left",duration:200,clickClose:!0,onOpen:null},n),a.is(":visible")&&a[0]!=t[0]?e.panelslider.close(function(){i(t,n)}):a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")||i(t,n)},e.panelslider.close=function(i){var a=e(".ps-active-panel"),s=a.data("duration"),o=a.outerWidth(!0),l={};if(a.length&&!a.is(":hidden")&&!n){switch(n=!0,a.data("side")){case"left":l.left="-="+o;break;case"right":l.right="-="+o}a.animate(l,s),t.animate({},s,function(){a.fadeOut(200),a.removeClass("ps-active-panel"),e("html").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("body").removeClass("overflow-hidden"),e("#eskimo-overlay").fadeOut(200),n=!1,i&&i()})}},e(document).bind("click keyup",function(i){var t=e(".ps-active-panel");"keyup"==i.type&&27!=i.keyCode||t.is(":visible")&&t.data("clickClose")&&e.panelslider.close()}),e(document).on("click",".ps-active-panel",function(e){e.stopPropagation()}),e.fn.panelslider=function(i){return this.on("click",function(t){var n=e(".ps-active-panel"),a=e(this.getAttribute("href"));n.is(":visible")&&a[0]==n[0]?e.panelslider.close():e.panelslider(a,i),t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()}),this}}(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-open").panelslider({side:"right",clickClose:!0,duration:400}),jQuery("body").find(".eskimo-panel-close").on("click",function(){return jQuery.panelslider.close(),!1})});
/* eslint-enable */

}
```

The rest of the file will remain unaffected and the linter would work as expected.

Comment: Please see my updated question where I show that I copy/paste js code inside ts file. I tried your solution but it didn't work. Maybe I did wrong.

Comment: Should work, check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-dawn-wl788) it has the same code, if you remove the top comment all problems appear on the console, try closing and opening VSCode.

Comment: When I check your codesandbox, after several seconds everything is red underlined. Even the 1st line of import of jquery is not found. Any idea ?